# How to find all of X's answers to Y's questions?

Tags: support

Assuming their existence, how would I find all instances in which user X answered Y's question?
I tried: `user:X user:Y` but this fails.

Comment: There is no way in the default search where you can intermix questions and answers (even though you're after *questions*, since it still requires some overlap/search criteria involving *answers*). You'll have to resort to the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/).